# Why didn't the United States sign the 1968 Vienna Convention on Road Traffic?

Tags: united-states, international-relations

I read on https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vienna_Convention_on_Road_Traffic&oldid=919574725#Contracting_parties:

> The United States and China are the most notable examples of non-signatory countries. Short-term tourists are not permitted to bring cars into China. All foreign-registered vehicles in China must display a Chinese vehicle registration plate.

Why didn't the United States sign the 1968 Vienna Convention on Road Traffic, whereas it had [ratified the 1949 Vienna Convention on Road Traffic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit#Countries_and_jurisdictions_that_recognize_IDP)?

Comment: Not only did the US not *ratify* the 1968 Convention, they didn't even *sign* it.

Comment: Also the US has even *ratified* the [1949  Convention on Road Traffic](https://treaties.un.org/Pages/ViewDetailsV.aspx?src=TREATY&mtdsg_no=XI-B-1&chapter=11&Temp=mtdsg5&lang=en). (Signed: 19 Sep 1949, Ratified: 30 Aug 1950).

Answer (score 7):

Those agreements standardized drivers license among other things.

The federal government lacks the power to regulate drivers licenses.

The 1949 agreement was for international driving permits, 68 had domestic permits.

Comment: Thanks, if the federal government lacks the power to regulate drivers licenses, how comes they ratified the 1949 Vienna Convention on Road Traffic?

Comment: The 49 agreement was international permits, the 68 would be domestic permits federal government doesn't regulate.

Comment: This sounds plausible. The '68 Convention sets out some precise criteria for the format of domestic permits in its Annex 6 (which is non-optional).

Comment: The federal government can do things it wouldn't normally be able to do when treaties are concerned, though (the ur-example possibly being the Migratory Bird Treaty Act).